# Must declare the scalar variable "@@RowCount" on SaveChangesAsync

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core-2.2, azure-synapse

I have a simple table insert in entity framework to add a record to a Azure SQL Data-Warehouse table. I get this error on context.SaveChanges() - SQLException: Must declare the scalar variable "@@ROWCOUNT

Reading a table works perfectly fine only the saving to a table fails.

context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges(); -> fails here.

Expected result - record should get inserted in the table
Actual result - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
Inner Exception
SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@@ROWCOUNT".

Comment: Please supply a [mcve] to make this question answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that EntityFramework is not supported for Azure SQL Data Warehouse. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/12868725-support-for-entity-framework

I used the SqlConnection and SqlCommand as a workaround.

```
        `using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var query = "insert into Users([Id]) values (@Id)";
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }`
```